# Is it a good idea to replace a net on a screen door without taking it down?

Tags: doors, mosquitoes

I need to replace a mosquito net on a sliding screen door. I've watched some videos and bought a kit with spline, slider tool and net.

I cannot remove the sliding door from its place.

Is it a good idea to replace the net when the door is standing vertically? I can mostly fix it in place with duct tape, but will I be able to align it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to press pretty hard to get the spline into the groove. Your duct tape plan should work. And if you don't like the result, pull it out and try again.

Comment: You don't have to press hard if the screen material is fiberglass, but then the challenge is keeping it in the groove as you work your way around. I've done this dozens of times and rarely succeed on the first try and have to pull it all out and start again at least once.